# Facebook scraper is ignoring the og tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm trying to fix the `og` tags for the site http://www.milkywayelementaryschool.hu

I have set the `og` meta tags for Facebook, already used the Debugger too, and it reports that is sees the meta tags for title, description and image, but decides, to use a smaller image, the title of the article and the name of the menu items instead. Why?

I'm completely lost. What I should do to fix it, so it shows what I have set in the share window?

Update:
Used the debugger again, problem seems to be:

After running a new scrape, it says that it found title, description, image, but pushing the "show existing scrape" tells that the url, title and desciption is missing. And that the 638x630 pixel picture is too small. (and the show existing refers to the scrape i have done seconds ago)

Comment: This is what Facebook see https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.milkywayelementaryschool.hu%2F . There is no og tags

Comment: Debug tool reports:
These are the raw tags that we found
Meta Tag <meta property="og:image:height" content="638" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:image:width" content="630" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.milkywayelementaryschool.hu/images/screen2.png" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:description" content="A Milky Way &#xc1;ltal&#xe1;nos Iskola honlapja" />
Meta Tag <meta property="og:title" content="Milky Way &#xc1;ltal&#xe1;nos Iskola" /> They are there, just before /head.

Comment: The errors I see are accurate - it says you don't have an og:url meta tag, the image URL is incorrect, and you have no fb:app_id meta tag - as far as I can see all three are accurate - your image URL isn't valid because it's missing the protocol identifier (e.g. http:// or https:// )

Comment: meta property="og:image" content="http:// www.milkywayelementaryschool.hu/images/screen2.png" - come again? (sorry, stackoverflow takes out the http, but it is there)

Comment: My problem is: it finds all the tags. Lists them under "based on the raw tags", you can see the picture at that field. And then goes on to ignore them.

Comment: @Gregdawn Hi i have the exact same problem. Facebook recognizes the tags in raw but ignores them. Did you solve the problem and would you mind sharing the solution with me ? Kind regards

Comment: Wrote to facebook about it, they have done something internally and replied they will fix it. Which they didn't. So it works with only the page I have reported to them.

Comment: good evening dear Gredawn - well i found out that we can scrape fb eg: see here: https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/
question: well can i scrape fb pages for a special key category - eg. 
female and  single  - is this possible!?